# PHP: Explode textarea lines as separate array element

Tags: php, textarea, explode

I have a textarea that contains phone numbers, each number in a separate line. I want to explode that string into an array using

```
explode("\n", $numbers);
```

or

```
explode("\r\n", $numbers);
```

This is not working. Please, help me.        Thanks!

Comment: If you are so smart, tell me, what is wrong here?

Comment: Did you mean to write `explode("\n", $numbers);` or `explode("\r\n", $numbers);`? Or are you actually writing both statements right next to each other as a single line like that?

Comment: You should post a little more code, the HTML form as well as a little more surrounding code.

Comment: `explode("\r\n", $numbers);` suppose to work.. well it is working for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) states: *Returns an array of strings*.

So you'll have to store the result. The `or` won't work that way either. If you don't know whether the input will contain `\n` or `\r\n`, you could do a replace to replace `\r` by an empty string, then explode on `\n`.

This should do the trick:

```
$numbers = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $numbers));
```

Comment: you're right, of course. User submitted data may not translate to the system EOL. comment withdrawn.

Answer (score 11):

`$records = preg_split('/[\r\n]+/', $mystring, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

This should do it.

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
<?php

 $input = $_POST['textarea_name'];
 $new_array = array_values(array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL, $input)));

 // explode -> convert textarea to php array (that lines split by new line)
 // array_filter -> remove empty lines from array
 // array_values -> reset keys of array

?>
```